# Book citation not showing publisher and address with ecta style

Tags: citing, natbib, bibliographystyle

when I put in

```
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{References_NB}
```

The following citation does not show the address & publisher:

```
@book{young_1958,
    author    = "Michael Young",
    title     = "The Rise of the Meritocracy",
    year      = "1958", % Citations: 2,998
    publisher = "Thames and Hudson",
    address   = "London"
}
```

In the main text, I did:

```
\begin{document}
\cite{young_1958} says ...
\end{document}
```

What comes out in my references is:
[image: Book Citation Screenshot]

I suppose the alternative way to sort it out is probably to define a new citation command that asks latex to show the book's publisher & address?
Further, how can I make the citation's title non-Italic?

Thank you so much!

Best,
Darcy

I don't know whether it's some packages that I cited that caused the disappearance of the publisher & address, so I copy-paste all the packages here.

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \definecolor{blue-green}{rgb}{0.0, 0.87, 0.87}
% \definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
% \definecolor{com}{rgb}{0, 0, 1} % com short for comment

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5in,bmargin=1.5in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\synctex=-1
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{dvipost}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, array}
\usepackage{float}

% \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% \usepackage{multicol, latexsym, amsmath, amssymb}
% \usepackage{blindtext}
% \usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{caption}
% \usepackage{tabu}
%    \usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table
% \usepackage{anysize} % Soporte para el comando \marginsize
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \setlength\parindent{0pt}
% \spanishdecimal{.}

\usepackage{fmtcount} % displaying latex counters
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}


\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Change tracking with dvipost
% \dvipostlayout
% \dvipost{osstart color push Red}
% \dvipost{osend color pop}
% \dvipost{cbstart color push Blue}
% \dvipost{cbend color pop}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxadded}[3]{\changestart#3\changeend}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxdeleted}[3]{%
\changestart\overstrikeon#3\overstrikeoff\changeend}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}       % customizable list environments
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{lem}{\protect\lemmaname}
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem{rem}{\protect\remarkname}
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{prop}{\protect\propositionname}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\parskip        = 0.25cm
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{subdepth}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{11}{8}{7} % \scriptsize is 8 pt



% The following  makes the remark boldface not italic
\newtheoremstyle{remark}        
  {}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{{\thmname{#1 }}{\thmnumber{#2}}{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}
\theoremstyle{remark}
% The following  makes the proofs boldface and not italic
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{{\bfseries #1.}}




\setlength{\bibsep}{1.25mm}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemii{\(\triangleright\)}
  \def\labelitemiii{\(\circ\)}
}

\makeatother

  \providecommand{\lemmaname}{Lemma}
  \providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}
  \providecommand{\remarkname}{Remark}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thank you for including code in your first question, it would be best if it could compile (in the future) as in begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` so that people can copy and paste it, but hopefully this is enough information for people to answer `:)`

Comment: Off-topic: `tmargin=1.5in,bmargin=1.5in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in` may be expressed more compactly as `vmargin=1.5in, hmargin=1in`.

Answer (score 1):

(updated this answer after I received further information from the OP)

The presence of the "comment" `% Citations: 2,998` in the `young_1958` entry generates the following BibTeX error message:

```
You're missing a field name---line 8 of file mybib.bib
 :     year      = "1958", 
 :                         % Citations: 2,998
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--missing publisher in young_1958
(There was 1 error message)
```

(Here, `mybib.bib` is the name of the scratch bib file I created to test your code.)

A general suggestion: If you think something may have gone wrong during the BibTeX run, it's a good idea to check in the .blg (short for "BibTeX log", I suppose) file. Put differently: Ignore BibTeX error messages at your own peril.

Omit this "comment", and everything behaves as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{young_1958,
    author    = "Michael Young",
    title     = "The Rise of the Meritocracy",
    year      = "1958", 
    publisher = "Thames and Hudson",
    address   = "London"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}

\begin{document}
\citet{young_1958}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Mico, thanks for the answer. However, it seems that ```ecta``` is indeed supposed to show the publisher & address, such as in https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-economic-ecta/.

Comment: @DJP - Please see the updated answer I just posted.